# Receiving 2 responses from Mapbox API using express GET request

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, axios, mapbox

I have a very basic app that takes a UK Postcode as a URL parameter and returns the longitude and latitude via the `Mapbox API`.

It seems I am receiving 2 responses: The first response is returned successfully and displayed on screen, then the second response is caught by my catch block with the following error `Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined` I understand the error but don't understand that why the app executes successfully (returns lng and lat to user) then shows an error?

./server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const MapApi = require('./datasources/map')

const Map = new MapApi;

server.get('/:postcode', async (req,res) => {

    const { postcode } = req.params

    const [lng, lat] = await Map.getLngLat( postcode )

    res.send(`Longitude: ${lng}, Latitude: ${lat}`) 
})

const { PORT_NUMBER } = process.env

server.listen(PORT_NUMBER, () => console.log('Listening on port ', PORT_NUMBER))
```

./datasources/map.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const axios = require('axios');

class MapApi {
    constructor(){
        this.baseURL = (search_term) => {
            return `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${search_term}.json?access_token=${process.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
        }
    }

    // Get Lng, Lat from Postocde
    async getLngLat (search_term) {
        return axios.get( this.baseURL(search_term) )
        .then(response => {
            return typeof response.data === "object" 
                ? response.data.features[0].geometry.coordinates
                : [0,0]
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error: ', err)
        })
    }

}

module.exports = MapApi
```

If i include the following line `` console.log(`Time ${Date.now()} - Type ${typeof response}`) `` in the then block of the axios request

I get the following console output >    
`Time 1575388974209 - Type object` 
`Time 1575388975073 - Type object` 
`Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined`

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(response)` inside the `.then()` of `getLatLng()`?

Comment: the plot thickens. I am receiving the correct response object then  ```{ type: 'FeatureCollection',
  query: [ 'faviconico' ],
  features: [],
  attribution:
   'NOTICE: © 2019 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare.' }```. So it seems to be requesting a favicon from https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/faviconico.json?access_token=${MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}

Comment: Mapbox's API isn't happy with the coords you gave it, it would seem. I would log the query string just before you use it to be sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: In poking around with the Mapbox api, it returns a featureless response if you just provide the postcode. A full street address (like 123 Main St Swindon SN2 2DQ) does return a feature collection.

Comment: Postcode.io web api does what you want, api.postcodes.io/postcodes/:postcode

Comment: @JDunken thank, great api but now its trying to request http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/favicon.ico for some reason